# How to check the error while login SAP GUI via Python codes

Tags: python, connection, sap-gui

I try to log in the SAP GUI by Python, but after I run the codes, I got the following error

> connection = application.OpenConnection("A101.TA2", True) File "<COMObject >", line 3, in OpenConnection pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (1000, 'saplogon', 'SAP Logon connection entry not found', None, 0, 0), None)

The login screen is like this
http://img1.imagehousing.com/0/sap-370961.png

I tried `A101`,`A101.TA2` `A101.TA2 PRD / ERi TEN` as connection name, all failed. what's should be correct connection name?

```
import win32com.client
import sys
import subprocess
import time

def saplogin():

    

  path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
  subprocess.Popen(path)
  time.sleep(3)

  SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
  if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
      return
  
  application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
  
  if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
      
      SapGuiAuto = None
      return
  
  connection = application.OpenConnection("A101.TA2", True)
  print('5')
  if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
      application = None
      SapGuiAuto = None
      return

  session = connection.Children(0)
  if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
      connection = None
      application = None
      SapGuiAuto = None
      return

  session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "USERNAME"
  session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "PASSWORD"
  session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

    


saplogin()
```

Comment: Check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66367542/9329965

Answer (score 0):

I do not work with Python, but I would take the full name in the connection string.

for example:

```
connection = application.OpenConnection("A101.TA2 PRD / Eri TEN", True)
```

Regards, ScriptMan