# class 'pywintypes.com_error' for running a SAP transaction

Tags: python, sap-gui

I am trying to use a script in Python (Spyder) to open SAP and run a transaction. to acheive this goal I recorded SAP vbscript and with couple of tweaks for Python usage it works fine until it gets to the middle of SAP script and it triggers the `class 'pywintypes.com_error'` ! 
The code I use to do this task is following. Any help on how to get around this issue is highly appreciated:

```
def saplogin():

    try:

        path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
        subprocess.Popen(path)
        time.sleep(2)

        SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
        if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            return

        application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return
        connection = application.OpenConnection("SAP")

        if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            application = None
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return

        session = connection.Children(0)
        if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            connection = None
            application = None
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return

        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "Uname"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "Pass"
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)




        session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane (98,16,False)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "S032"
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey (0)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/radP_MATL").select
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_LTPC").selected = False
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_FEVOR-LOW").text = "86A"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/radP_SORT3").setFocus
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/radP_SORT3").select
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
        session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[1]/menu[2]").select
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[1,0]").select
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[1,0]").setFocus
        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = "D:\PowerBIKhodam\WIP_Status\86A"
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "S32.xls"
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 12
        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press

    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])
    finally:
        session = None
        connection = None
        application = None
        SapGuiAuto = None

saplogin()
```

Comment: That is not VBScript.

Comment: Thanks, can you give more details please?! I am not sure what exactly is wrong?

Comment: I would appreciate if some one with the experience in this field would comment to avoid leaving it unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

I used the same code, but in this part:

```
"except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])"
```

You need to include other line: `"print(sys.exc_info())"`.

Remove the `[0]` and try again. Possibly will show a mensage like:

> "(, com_error(-2147352567, 'Exceção.', (619, 'SAP Frontend Server', 'The control could not be found by id.' "

Afther this, you have more information for debbuging.

Answer (score 2):

Works with Phyton 32 and 64 bits, versions 3.9 and 2.7.

Three things that you need to take into account:

1. SAP Gui scripting is disabled by default on the SAP application server-side, causing exactly this error, so your Basis need to enable it first in SAP Gui transaction RZ11 by setting profile parameter `sapgui/user_scripting=TRUE`
2. In SAP Logon SAP Gui Option `Accessibility & Scripting` -> `Scripting User Settings` `Enable scripting` marked, `Notify when a script attaches to SAP GUI` unmarked, `Notify when a script opens a connection` unmarked.
3. SAP Logon and SAP Gui on your PC needs to be switched off

Also, check Stefan's Schnell blog post ["How to use SAP GUI Scripting inside Python Programming Language"](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/19/how-to-use-sap-gui-scripting-inside-python-programming-language/) with comments.

Comment: I had the same issue. But thanks to @greg , after switching off SAP Logon and GUI and executing the script solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you tried this or not but it looks like you just have "SAP" as your connection name.  Look in your SAP Logon Pad and get the FULL connection name there.